# mysql query, grouping, if, etc

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*),
  SUBSTR(datetime_acc, 1, 10),
  type_acc
FROM payment_acc
WHERE type_acc LIKE '%monthly%'
GROUP BY SUBSTR(datetime_acc, 1, 10), type_acc
ORDER BY datetime_acc, type_acc
```

```
 count  date        type_acc       
------  ----------  ---------------
     4  2011-01-20  monthly payment
     3  2011-01-20  failed monthly 
     5  2011-01-21  monthly payment
    10  2011-01-22  failed monthly 
    11  2011-01-22  monthly payment
     1  2011-01-23  monthly payment
     4  2011-01-24  monthly payment
     1  2011-01-24  failed monthly 
     6  2011-01-25  failed monthly 
     6  2011-01-25  monthly payment
    16  2011-01-26  failed monthly 
    10  2011-01-26  monthly payment
```

But I'm trying to get the failed and passed on lines together in different columns

```
success  failed  date        
-------  ------  ----------  
      4       3  2011-01-20  
      5      10  2011-01-21  
     11    NULL  2011-01-22  
      1    NULL  2011-01-23  
      4       1  2011-01-24  
      6       6  2011-01-25  
     10      16  2011-01-26
```

Any clues?

Comment: I think your expected result looks wrong. Why do you expect 10 failures for 2011-01-21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your existing query in a view and then query the view as follows:

```
SELECT
    T1.date,
    T2.count AS success_count,
    T3.count AS failed_count
FROM yourview T1
LEFT JOIN yourview T2 ON T1.date = T2.date AND T2.type_acc = 'monthly payment'
LEFT JOIN yourview T3 ON T1.date = T3.date AND T3.type_acc = 'failed monthly'
GROUP BY T1.date
```

Results:

```
date        success_count  failed_count
2011-01-20  4              3           
2011-01-21  5              NULL        
2011-01-22  11             10          
2011-01-23  1              NULL        
2011-01-24  4              1           
2011-01-25  6              6           
2011-01-26  10             16
```

Comment: Do you want the firstborn or the second??

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries are the only way I see this being possible.  It does mean a lot of derived tables though.  Use the EXPLAIN option to see how ugly it is.

> SELECT b.intSuccess, c.intFailed, a.dateThis 
>   FROM 
>   (SELECT DATE(datetime_acc) AS dateThis FROM payment_acc) a 
>   LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS intFailed, DATE(datetime_acc) AS dateThis FROM payment_acc WHERE type_acc LIKE "%failed%" AND type_acc LIKE "%monthly%" GROUP BY DATE(datetime_acc)) b ON b.dateThis=a.dateThis 
>   LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS intSuccess, DATE(datetime_acc) AS dateThis FROM payment_acc
>   WHERE type_acc NOT LIKE "%failed%" AND type_acc LIKE "%monthly%" GROUP BY (datetime_acc)) c ON c.dateThis=a.dateThis 
>   ORDER BY a.dateThis;